# I would like to know the reason why springBoot3 removed spring. factories

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to know the reason why springBoot3 removed spring. factories

I tried looking at issuse and the usage documentation, but I didn't see a specific reason from that.

This question is confusing to me because the new version also reads files and there doesn't seem to be any difference between them------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

It's related to autoconfiguration in spring. See this issue  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29872